# How to use =FILTER to create a dropdown list in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on setting up a spreadsheet to easily review and select available discounts for a specific item.
For example,

| SKU | Discount Amount | Discount Minimum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00005 | $1.05 | 1 |
| 00005 | $1.50 | 10 |

I have a formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER("Min:"&'QD''s'!$N$1:$N$18606&"-Disc:$"&'QD''s'!$P$1:$P$18606,'QD''s'!$K$1:$K$18606=INDIRECT("Sheet2!$A"&ROW()),""))
```

which generates a comma delimited list of the information I'm looking for in the drop down (eg below)

```
Min:1-Disc:$1.05, Min:10-Disc:$1.50, Min:20-Disc:$1.75
```

However, when I drop this formula into the "List" section of data validation, it does not seem to work. I have used this to create a comma delimited list, that when I paste as values then paste into the data validation it does work.

Is there any formula (possibly similar to =INDIRECT()) that would be able to force the list to read this string as text?

Comment: You will need to put just the filter part of the formula in a range then refer to that range using the `#`.  Ie if you put the formula in Sheet2!A1 then you would use `=Sheet2!A1#`  DataValidation does not allow the use of dynamic arrays.

Comment: Hey @ScottCraner There is no dynamic array being provided into the Data Validation, as far as the data validation should see it should be a comma delimited list. Unfortunately I can't use =FILTER in a cell then reference it because I will have thousands of rows, and =FILTER spills into the cells below so it would need a different column for each individual SKU.

Comment: If you have different drop downs depending on what is chosen previousle,  then you will need a column per choice and you will want to name the range the same as the previous choices.  Then you would use `=Indirect(A3)` where A3 is the previous choice.  You cannot do a dynamic changing list directly in DataVAlidation or Conditional Formatting.  They are not allowed.  This is a well known limitation.  You will need helper column(s).

Comment: BTW, I said `Sheet2` in my comment but I meant it as an example.  Instead point it at  a blank sheet.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Also `INDIRECT("Sheet2!$A"&ROW())` can be `INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,ROW())` to avoid the volatile INDIRECT.